# Upload a server created image to FTP server

Tags: php, image, ftp, pdo, jpeg

I have read my code again and again, but I can't figure out whats is wrong..

script:

```
    <?
    require_once("../constant/constant.php");
    if($_POST['action'] == 'imgsave'){

    $admin = $_POST['admin'];
    $profile = $_POST['profile'];

    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE profile_id = '".$profile."'");
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $targ_w = 180;
    $targ_h = 120;

    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg('../uploads/'.$profile.'.jpg');

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($targ_w, $targ_h);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    //Grab new image
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($tmp);
    $image = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    imagedestroy($src);

    //Create temporary file and write to it
    $fp = tmpfile();
    fwrite($fp, $image);
    rewind($fp);

    //Upload new image
    $conn_id = ftp_connect('ftp.test.com');
    ftp_login($conn_id,'user','pass');
    ftp_fput($conn_id,'/profiles/'.$row['path'].'/preview2.jpg', $fp, FTP_BINARY);
    fclose($fp);

    }
    ?>
```

It is combined with the jCrop script and all I wanted is to modify the original script to post it to FTP..

```
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder.$filename);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($targ_w, $targ_h);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
    imagejpeg($tmp, $folder.'t_'.$filename,100);

    imagedestroy($tmp);
    imagedestroy($src);
```

As you can see, the original script is very simple.. and I think I got stuck in how advanced it became.. Can anybody see the solution, or maybe give me a hint about what else to do..

Comment: What errors/warnings/notifications do you get?

Comment: from ob_get_clean manual page: "ob_get_clean() essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean()."

Comment: I am feeling so stupid right now.. the script is 100% working... I just didn't need to put '../' in front of the constant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is working...! No problems!